# How to pass the textbox id to javascript function in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, function, validation, dom-events

I am developing an application in which I have a asp.net form with a lot of textboxes.I need to use the same JavaScript function for all the textboxes to validate whether it contains any non alphabetic character in it. How can I use the same method for all the textboxes? I am stuck at how could I pass the id of the textbox to the JavaScript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
       function CheckAlphabet(textboxId)
 {
 if (!document.getElementById('<%=textboxId.ClientId %>').value.match("/^[a-zA-Z]+/"))
 return false;   
}
</script>
```

asp.net code part is like this....

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="select" ID="TxtEmpFirstname"   onkeydown="CheckAlphabet(TxtEmpFirstname)"
                            runat="server" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
```

The Javascript code gave an error. Please help with passing the id of the asp.net textbox. I need to use the same Javascript function for many textboxes to validate for non alphabet characters in the textbox. Please help.

Comment: The suggestions did not work... The only way worked is by using the javascript function without the arguments. My question is how can i use the same function to validate many textboxes? Should i have to write down the entire function each time???

Answer (score 1):

Right approach would be carefully look at code and see what runs on server and what runs in the browser (i.e. print the code and mark in 2 colors)...

You onkeydown="CheckAlphabet(TxtEmpFirstname)" is mix of server side and client side intentions: you should construct client ID with server side code instead of TxtEmpFirstname and remove it from the function itself.

```
onkeydown="CheckAlphabet('<%=textboxId.ClientId %>')"
```

Comment: The suggestions did not work... The only way worked is by using the javascript function without the arguments. My question is how can i use the same function to validate many textboxes? Should i have to write down the entire function each time???

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function CheckAlphabet(textboxId)
{
   if (!textboxId.value.match("/^[a-zA-Z]+/"))
   return false;   
}

<asp:TextBox CssClass="select" ID="TxtEmpFirstname" onkeydown="javascript:CheckAlphabet(this)" runat="server" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function CheckAlphabet(textboxId){
        if (!document.getElementById(textboxId).value.match("/^[a-zA-Z]+/")) return false;   
    }
</script>


<asp:TextBox CssClass="select" ID="TxtEmpFirstname" onkeydown='CheckAlphabet("<%=TxtEmpFirstname.ClientId %>")' runat="server" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
```

Notice that the client-side script only references the contents of the variable that is passed to it.  When the `TextBox` is rendered to the page, the inline tag (`<%=...%>`) will be converted into the client-side ID of the `input` field.

Also take note of the quote usage.  When you put an inline server-side command in the property of a server-side tag, you have to wrap the property with single quotes and then use double quotes to represent literal strings in what will be the final output.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
function CheckAlphabet(textboxId)
{
  if (!document.getElementById(textboxId).value.match("/^[a-zA-Z]+/"))
  return false;   
}

<asp:TextBox CssClass="select" ID="TxtEmpFirstname" onkeydown="CheckAlphabet(this.value)" runat="server" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
```

javascript code will be complained after server side codes compiled